# Matching hyphenated word

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to search for hyphenated words in a string 
e.g. Hello-world
with only two words in it

I have wrote following regex:

```
\b([a-zA-Z])+(-)([a-zA-Z])+\b
```

http://regexr.com/38t6l

Unfortunately it is matching words in 3 or more letter hyphenated string too
e.g. **test-test**-test
**test-test**-**test-test**
how to un-match above

Comment: so what output do you expect in your xamples ?

Comment: its working fine but selecting extra words withing a string e.g. test-test-test
test-test-test-test

Comment: I want to select only 2 hyphenated words... the above regex is selecting 3, 4 hyphenated words

Comment: so 123test-test should be a match as well as ctrl-z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex :

```
/\b(?<!-)\w+-\w+(?!-)\b/g
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/uW7tV6

the website you are using only supports javascript regex, so lookbehind will not work there.
Use this site, its better.